# Tracking a Swipe

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, core-graphics

Is there a way for me to check if a swipe gesture went through particular points on the screen ?

I am trying to achieve something like this :

http://screenshots.en.sftcdn.net/en/scrn/3337000/3337188/dot-lock-03-356x535.jpg

Please let me know if the approach of tracking the swipes is not appropriate for achieving this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think the swipe gesture is what you want.  You'd be better off detecting the initial touch with `touchesBegan:withEvent:` and then checking that all of your points were hit in the `touchesMoved:withEvent:` messages before you receive a `touchesEnded:withEvent:` or `touchesCancelled:withEvent:` message.